# Using flexbox, left-align and right-align elements in one row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In the old days I would have used two containers and floated one left and the other right using clearfix. But I think that method is a bit antiquated with flex capabilities being well supported now.

Problem is I have no idea how to lay this out using flex.

Here is a screenshot with some buttons. Secondary action is aligned left and the other two primary actions should be right aligned.

[image]

Here is the markup I have:

```
<footer>
    <button>Back</button>
    <span class="primary-btns">
        <button>Cancel</button>
        <button>Go</button>
    </span>
</footer>
```

Can someone tell me what CSS flex methods I should use here?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can just use `justify-content: space-between`

```css
footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <button>Back</button>
  <span class="primary-btns">
    <button>Cancel</button>
    <button>Go</button>
  </span>
</footer>
```

Update: You can also do this without `span` with `margin-left: auto` [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/800/)

Answer (score 16):

You don't even need a nested container in this case.

Modern CSS technologies (flex and grid) make this layout simple and require just one container.

```css
footer {
  display: flex;
}

button:first-child {
  margin-right: auto;
}

button {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <button>Back</button>
  <button>Cancel</button>
  <button>Go</button>
</footer>
```

Flex auto margins consume all free space in the specified direction.

This would also work:

```
button:nth-child(2) { margin-left: auto }
```

All about auto margins here: [Methods for Aligning Flex Items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)